# Referencing style in APA format

Tags: citing, apa-style, agutex

AGU publications now require preparing manuscript in APA format, [but the template provided on their website](https://publications.agu.org/files/2017/12/agu-template-20171201.zip) is old and not according to APA format. I do not know what modification should I make to prepare my draft in APA.

Can someone suggest me, how can I do that?

Comment: Related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35809/how-do-i-use-apa-style-citations-with-bibtex . See the answer. You have to include the command `\usepackage{apacite}` in your preamble and then the commands you see there for the bibliography. You will need a separate file with extension ".bib" in the main directory and then you have to compile pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex->pdflatex. The citations have to be in the .bib file and the form of them is explained in the section : "Bibliography management with Bibtex" here: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex

Comment: My above comment is not useful on the specific template but helps about apa style in bibtex. I tried and finding conflicts everywhere... Started with the `natbib` that is included in cls file... but removing it makes more errors... Sorry... I thing that they have to create a new template than repairing this (tried with agujournalsample.tex)

Comment: Sorry that didn't really helped, but they have to provide a template... The provided is really bad and outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as you can read on the [webpage of agu](https://publications.agu.org/author-resource-center/checklists-and-templates/) they mention:

> Please note, AGU is in the process of updating our latex template with
>   our updated style.  The below main manuscript tex template does not
>   yet include AGU’s updated style. **You may continue** using this template
>   and **do not need to alter** the style. During production, the typesetters
>   will apply the updated style, which you will notice in author proofs

So please use the old template until they make the new one public ...

Comment: I figured that out after i posted the question, but then I was curious to know how it is done.