# Using Apa-Citation in TeXstudio not working

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX (TeXstudio) and I am currently configuring my file and also adding my first sources. The default of the citation is APA 7th generation.

Now I have created a `.bib` file using Citavi and want to reference it.

When I enter the following command, the following error occurs and it is also not cited in APA:

[image]

Is it because "`apa`" is not a proper bibliographystlye? Which is the correct one? Can someone help me with my problem?

Comment: Check [bibtex styles](https://www.bibtex.com/bibliography-styles/). There are some `apalike` variants and specific [apa](https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-misc-apa/). You may have to download the `bst` files.

Comment: `apa` is a valid `\bibliographystyle`, but the `apa.bst` that is available on CTAN (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apabst) and that you will get if you use `\bibliographystyle{apa}` unless you are doing something special was written in 1992 and will most likely not implement current 7th edition APA style. It's hard to tell what exactly is going wrong in your example, we need to see the relevant `.bib` entry and we need all the code as copy-and-pasteable plain text, not as an image. (Note also that the error message LaTeX produces are actually more verbose, your editor truncates them).

Comment: If you want APA 7 the only LaTeX-based solution that I know of is `biblatex-apa`.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, you don't mean to be using `\bibliography{apa}`, this isn't bundled with a current TeX Live distribution and [`apa.bst`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apabst) which you are most likely using is more than 30 years old, pre-dating both LaTeX2e and the 5th if not also the 4th edition of the APA style.  Probably, you want to look into the likes of [`apacite`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite) and [`biblatex-apa`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa), and the questions [How to APA 6th in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2628/106162), [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793/106162), and [How do I use APA-style citations with BibTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35809/106162) on this site.

However, it does appear to be possible to successfully still use [`apa.bst`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apabst). The fragment of the error message visible in your screenshot seems to point to a macro ending `...oncite{` as being undefined, looking at [`apa.bst`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apabst) it's almost certainly pointing to the `\astroncite` macro therein.
[`apa.bst`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/apabst) is apparently meant to be used in conjunction with [`astron`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/astron) which provides the `\astroncite` macro, this appears to work, however [`astron`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/astron) is also 30 years old and not distributed with TeX Live, and the more modern [`natbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) can be used in place.

```
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{Astekin.2018,
    author = "Author, A",
    title = "Paper",
    journal = "Journal",
    year = 2018,
    volume = 1,
    number = 2,
    pages = 3,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{astron}

\begin{document}
\cite{Astekin.2018}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```