# help me for APA citation templet

Tags: citing, apa-style

I want to the apa reference style in an article. Can any one can help me in this regard. I am using kile to compile the LaTex file in UBUNTU platform.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Well, , you can use `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` in your preamble.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is adapted from [Tabular bibliography with 2 cols for @inbook, @article etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157359) and [How to APA 6th in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/how-to-apa-6th-in-latex) It also use http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.fr/2010/03/apa-style-references-in-latex.html to provide you this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{mwe2012,
  author = {Smith, A. and Johnson, B. and Willians, C.},
  title = {The three most common surnames in the United States of America},
  journal = {Review of Useless Knowledge},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {8},
  number = {1},
  pages = {290--290}
}

@ARTICLE{mwe2011,
  author = {Miller, J. and Brown, D.},
  title = {Most used surnames in fake passports},
  journal = {Journal of Nosense Ranks},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {5},
  number = {3},
  pages = {1--130},
  pmid = {1234567},
  url = {http://www.mwe.com/mwe2011},
  doi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/jnr.2011.01.01},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

You can cite \cite{mwe2012} or \citeA{mwe2012} or also \citeyear{mwe2012}

You can cite \cite{mwe2011} or \citeA{mwe2011} or also \citeyear{mwe2011}

\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

You can compile it in ubuntu using:

```
latexmk test.tex
```